# Changing searchFields in seacrhGrid - jqGrid

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I'm using **jqGrid 4.3.1**, and i have the following grid and seachGrid.

[image: jqGrid - grid]

[image: jqGrid - searchGrid]

I need to **change the values** of the searchField in the searchGrid, however i cant change the grid. 
I know that the search grid uses the colModels to build the searchField options, but there is anyway that i could set this values my self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do the next **if you can change table properties but not the names of the columns in the colModel**.

Edit the search options of the table ([Info here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching&s[]=search&s[]=options)) and add the property `beforeShowSearch` wich is a function triggered before showing the form to the user. And inside this function use this selector `$("#fbox_grps td.columns select")` for the specified select in the image and works with it like you do with any select.